# При попытке авторизации на VK ошибка - Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

Tags: swift, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

При попытке нажать клавишу "Разрешить доступ" выходит ошибка:

> Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import VK_ios_sdk

class ViewController: UIViewController, VKSdkDelegate, VKSdkUIDelegate {


    func vkSdkShouldPresent(_ controller: UIViewController!) {
        print("vkSdkShouldPresent")
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func vkSdkNeedCaptchaEnter(_ captchaError: VKError!) {
        print("vkSdkNeedCaptchaEnter")
    }

    func vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinished(with result: VKAuthorizationResult!) {
        print(result.token)
    }


    func vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinishedWithResult(result:VKAuthorizationResult?) {
        print(result?.token)
    }

    func vkSdkUserAuthorizationFailed() -> Void {
        print("vkSdkUserAuthorizationFailed")
    }

    func vkSdkAuthorizationStateUpdatedWithResult(with result: VKAuthorizationResult) -> Void {
        print("vkSdkAuthorizationStateUpdatedWithResult")
    }

    func vkSdkAccessTokenUpdated(newToken: VKAccessToken?, oldToken: VKAccessToken?) -> Void {
        print("vkSdkAuthorizationStateUpdatedWithResult")
    }

    func vkSdkTokenHasExpired(expiredToken: VKAccessToken?) -> Void {
        print("vkSdkTokenHasExpired")
    }

    let permission = ["email", "photos", "wall", "offline"]
    var vkInst = VKSdk.initialize(withAppId: "XXXXXXX")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func authButton(_ sender: Any) {

        vkInst?.register(self)
        vkInst?.uiDelegate = self
        VKSdk.wakeUpSession(permission, complete: {(state: VKAuthorizationState, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if state == .authorized {
                print("Yes")
            } else {
                VKSdk.authorize(self.permission)
            }
            return
        })
    }

}
```

В файл Info.plist добавил следующее:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>vk</string>
    <string>vk-share</string>
    <string>vkauthorize</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>vk.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Вот что выводится в консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
На сколько я понял, я не настроил URL-схему. Я еще добавил в Info.plist следующее:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>"Bundle Identifier"</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>"APP_ID"</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

После добавления этих значений, ошибка исчезла, и при нажатии на "Разрешить" страница просто обновляется. А также выдает такую ошибку в консоль:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у Вас есть `redirect_uri`? Подробнее про авторизацию нативными методами ВКонтакте здесь: https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_group

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример?

Comment: К сожалению нет, я работал с VK API на других платформах, но не на Swift. Попробуйте найти документацию по Вашему API в интернете, думаю там описана данная ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка (10814) лишь указывает на то, что по умолчанию SDK пытается запустить VK App на устройстве для проведения процедуры логина, если его  (приложения) нет, то переходит к запуску WebView, так что, по большому счету, она несет информационный характер.

Опишу, как мне удалось решить подобную проблему!
Для начала нужно проверить правильность URL схемы, корректно ли указан APP_ID в CFBundleURLSchemes в info.plist. Должен иметь вид «vk0123456», где 0123456 - это ID Вашего Standalone- приложения. Далее добавляем в методе делегата AppDelegate сл методы:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("url: \(url)")

    return true
}

private func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    VKSdk.processOpen(url as URL?, fromApplication: sourceApplication)
    print("url: \(url)")

    return true
}
```

Если все настроено верно, то в один из методов придет ответ от VK, в котором и будет token! Возможно в Вашем случае именно так и происходит, но Вы этого не видите.

Далее в методе wakeUpSession в момент авторизации отключаем использование Safari (.disableSafariController):

```
VKSdk.wakeUpSession(scope) { (state, error) in
        if state == .authorized {
            //autorized
            print("User authorized")
        } else {
            //autorized neaded
            VKSdk.authorize(self.scope, with: .disableSafariController)
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Надеюсь, помог! Удачи!

UPD!!!
Если указать в AppDelegate:

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    VKSdk.processOpen(url, fromApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String)
    print("url: \(url)")

    return true
}

private func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    VKSdk.processOpen(url as URL?, fromApplication: sourceApplication)
    print("url: \(url)")

    return true
}
```

то можно не отключать использование Safari в wakeUpSession. В первый метод делегата придет ответ от VK, который и подхватит SDK!